# Figure breaks subsequent text (when it's no longer 'really' there)

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

The following screenshot is from a large document, so I can't provide a working example because the problem will strongly depend on the preceding text, I believe.

I use this document class:

`\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside=on, BCOR=10mm]{scrreprt}`

The figure is included like this:

```
...

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{GHZTestNature2000}
    \caption{GHZ correlations, taken from \emph{Beyond Measure} \cite[p. 175]{BeyondMeasure}}
    \label{fig:GHZTestNature}
\end{wrapfigure}

...
```

The aforementioned screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the first line in Section 2.5: 'As alluded to earlier, H. Stapp declared Bell’s theorem ’the most profound discovery of science’ [95, p. 271].' is broken, although it's not necessary and it looks ugly (to me). How can I prevent this from happening?

The included graphic is cropped maximally, i.e. there is not a large white section in the original image, in case you're wondering.

Comment: Using the optional argument of `wrapfig` as for example in `\begin{wrapfigure}[14]{R}{0.38\textwidth}` could help here.

Comment: yes, that solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that wrapfigure assumes every line takes \baselineskip of vertical space, so anything which takes up more (including \parskip) will throw it off.  You can also use \WFclear, but only between paragraphs.